# How to solve when a classic tween is not working with stop() at the first second?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

How to solve when the object is not moving with classic tweening motion in action script coding with stop() command? At my timeline, my object is functioning well with the classic tweening motion. But when I pressed ctrl enter, the object is not moving with the motion.

I've tried on 'gotoAndStop' and 'gotoAndPlay' command.

The code below are the first scene coding and there is a button. When press the button, it will go to scene two.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

GWbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, China);
function China(e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndPlay(1, 'Scene 2');
}
```

In scene two, i have create a classic tweening in the timeline for an object and i include stop() command in the coding as below. When ctrl enter, the tweening is not functioning.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

nextbtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, next1);
function next1(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndPlay(17);
}
```

I expect the output of my object is moving with classic tweening and the stop() command.

Comment: I'd say it is the expected behaviour - since you put a stop() command at the first frame of Scene 2 and the framehead moves there upon a click on China. What's the purpose of this stop() command?

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies with scene 2 frame 1 having a stop(); in your code. Do this to stop the tweening on frame 16:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//stop(); //remove this line

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);
function checkFrame(event:Event):void {
    if (currentFrame == 16) {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);
        stop();
    }
}

nextbtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, next1);
function next1(event:MouseEvent):void{
    nextbtn1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, next1);  //also kindly add this, its good practice
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);
    gotoAndPlay(17);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help  @user1234567